# Sort array using nested property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've an array of objects of type `A`. Every instance of `A` has a property of type `B`, which has a property of type `NSString`:

```
@interface A : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) B * b;

@end

@interface B : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString * s;

@end

A * a1 = // init
A * a2 = // init
NSArray * arr = @[a1,a2];
```

I would sort the array `arr` using property `s` contained in `B`. It's possible using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can create an `NSSortDescriptor` and then call `sortUsingDescriptors` on your array using that `NSSortDescriptor` as the argument

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortByString = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"myString" ascending:NO];
[myMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByString]];
```